# Issue with DecryptByKeyAutoAsymKey when Password Parameter is not Null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, encryption

I'm attempting to set-up some encryption on a test database.  Currently, I'm creating an asymmetric key that uses a user-provided password to encrypt the private key.  I then use this to encrypt a symmetric key that I create.

```
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY myAsymmetricKey
WITH ALOGRITHM = RSA_2048
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'mySecurePassword'
GO

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY mySymmetricKey 
WITH ALOGRITHM = AES_256
ENCRYPTION BY ASYMMETRIC KEY myAsymmetricKey
GO
```

I'm able to successfully encrypt the desired column(s) in the target database table

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY mySymmetricKey
DECRYPTION BY ASYMMETRIC KEY myAsymmetricKey WITH PASSWORD = 'mySecurePassword'

UPDATE myTable
SET EmailAddressEncrypted = ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('mySymmetricKey'), EmailAddress)

CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY mySymmetricKey
```

My issues relates to the decryption of the data.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to do this inside a stored procedure with the caller passing in the password.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Foo
    @id int,
    @password varchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TargetID,
           EmailAddress
           CAST(DECRYPTBYKEYAUTOASYMKEY(ASYMKEY_ID('myAsymmetricKey'), @password, emailAddressEncrypted) AS VARCHAR(125)) 
    FROM myTable
    WHERE TargetID = @id      
END
```

Unfortunately, when I attempt to create this procedure I receive the following error:

> Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 2 of DecryptByKeyAutoAsymKey function.

I'm confused by this as when I look at the [MSDN page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365420%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) for DecrypByKeyAutoAsymKey it says the argument 2 "akey_password" is:

> Is the password that protects the private key of the asymmetric key. Can be NULL if the private key is protected by the database master key. akey_password is varchar.

Their example on the page only uses NULL as the value for this argument and this doesn't work here since I don't believe I'm encrypting the private key with the DMK.  Any help/suggestions on what I'm doing wrong here or a better way to implement this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

*Note:  This is on SQL Server 2008*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the documentation on the MSDN page for this is incorrect.  The datatype for "akey_password" is **nvarchar**, not **varchar**.  Using a parameter of type **nvarchar** works for the decryption.

I hope this helps others who encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Using nVarchar is a good idea. And Also try using Convert instead of Cast.
Cast didn't work for me.